# Unknown suffix 'l' used for variable 'server_id' (value 'logBinIndex')

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

while i'm executing this command  **mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql**  , i'm getting this error :

```
2019-07-11T10:07:04.599756Z 0 [ERROR] Unknown suffix 'l' used for variable 'server_id' (value 'logBinIndex')

2019-07-11T10:07:04.599796Z 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Error while setting value 'logBinIndex' to 'server_id'

2019-07-11T10:07:04.599815Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I'm not using **systemctl** or **service** command for executing this, i'm using **custom script** to executing this command.

*Using Environments;*

- **Ubuntu 18.04**
- **mysql Distrib 5.7.26**

Comment: Look my.ini for correct [server_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_server_id) value. it must be integer.

Comment: @Akina  Is this is custom file , because MySQL have default my.cnf file , also ini is windows file.  Are you sure about this.

Comment: Yes, I mean instance settings file. my.cnf in your case if you use default filename.